# Why the compiler does this division

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to optimize nbody algorithm and this operation is expensive

```
real s = jMass / POW(distSqr,3.0/2.0);
```

so I tried to convert in:

```
s = jMass * POW(distSqr, -3.0/2.0);
```

but the compiler gcc with -Ofast option does the division anyway, why?

Comment: Did you check the assembler output or is this just your assumption? I think the `POW` function is way more expensive than the division.

Comment: I checked it with perf record, in the assembly code the division takes the 50% and other are multiplications

Comment: Could it be that `POW` with a negative exponent is more expensive than with a positive exponent?

Comment: Just a question: you say that this division is eating your performance. Instead of trying to optimise the performance of the division itself, you might ask yourself the question why this division is happening that many times. Is it possible that you have a routine which performs this division repeatedly, while it could simply do it once and hold on to the results, instead of doing it over and over again?

Comment: @Dominique the operation is in a O(N^2) complexity, so yes.

Comment: That doesn't look like ordinary C code.  What's `real`?  and `POW`?  and `distSqr`?  Question is meaningless without such context.  Give us a [mcve] so we can confirm for ourselves!

Comment: Why don't you just write `-1.5` instead of `-3.0/2.0` if the division hurts you so much?

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller The change has no impact on performance

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oKjATF) the compiler optimizes to a square root, a multiplication, and a division. It may be the compiler designers figure a square root and a division are faster than `pow`. If you get different code, show a [mre] along with compiler version and the switches used to compile.

Comment: @Chariot If the change has no impact on performance, it can only mean one thing: the division of the two literals never happened in the first place, it was optimized away as expected. The divisions you see in your perf record happen at another place, probably in the POW function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll have to make several assumptions here (that the variables are all type `double`, and that `POW` is a macro that expands to `pow`):

```
#include <math.h>

double f0(double a, double b) {
    return a / pow(b, 1.5);
}

double f1(double a, double b) {
    return a * pow(b, -1.5);
}
```

This gives me (on x86):

```asm-x86
f0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    sqrtsd  %xmm2, %xmm2
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm2
    divsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
f1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm2
    sqrtsd  %xmm2, %xmm2
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm2
    divsd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Transforming `pow(x, 1.5)` into `x * √x` is a reasonable optimisation, and the consequent division is still much faster than calling the expensive `pow()` function.  In other words, the compiler has quite reasonably chosen to represent `pow(x, -1.5)` as  `1/(x*√x)` when using `-Ofast`.